# CSS Animation inside the border-radius div

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I am trying to animate the images inside the another div border-radius. I have found the script here which auto rotate the image but i want the image to be placed inside the border-radius just for example like this screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ggrl.jpg

Here is my all codes

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8wkaT

HTML:

```
<div class="foodimg">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/litX96U.jpg" class="foodround" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Z3Rcoad.jpg" class="foodround" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WtVOxWa.jpg" class="foodround" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/idv5HXP.jpg" class="foodround" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.foodimg {
    border-radius: 200px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
}
```

JS:

```
var $imgs = $(".foodimg").find("img"),
    i = 0;

function changeImage() {
    var next = (++i % $imgs.length);
    $($imgs.get(next - 1)).fadeOut(500);
    $($imgs.get(next)).fadeIn(500);
}

var interval = setInterval(changeImage, 5000);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
.foodimg {
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
}
.foodimg img {
    max-height: 320px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8wkaT/3